# Difference between Data.List and Data.Char

Tags: haskell

In Haskell, what is the difference between a program with the heading

```
module Main where

import Data.List
```

and

```
module Main where

import Data.Char
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

These are the toy programs I am using to learn:

Program 1:

```
   module Main where

    import Data.Char

    prepets1 = ["cat", "dog", "scorpion", "cobra"]
    prepets2 = ["cat", "dog"]
    prepets3 = ["cat", "scorpion"]
    prepets4 = [prepets2, prepets3]

    data Pet = Pet {name :: String,
            venomous :: Bool,
            cost :: Integer }
        deriving (Eq, Show)

    venomous' :: String -> Bool
    venomous' = (>3). length

    cost' :: String -> Integer
    cost' = sum . map (fromIntegral . ord)

    petify :: String -> Pet
    petify s = Pet s (venomous' s) (cost' s)

    pets1 = map petify prepets1

    pets2 = [Pet s (venomous' s) (cost' s) | s <- prepets1]

    ouch1 :: [String] -> Bool
    --is any string here the name of a venomous pet?
    ouch1 xs = True

    ouch2 :: [[String]] -> Bool
    -- Is any string here the name of a veno,ous pet?
    ouch2 xs = False

    printpets = putStrLn . unlines. map show

    blankline = putStrLn "\n"

    main = do
        blankline
        print $ petify "cat"
        blankline
        print $ petify "scorpion"
        blankline
        printpets pets1
        blankline
        printpets pets2
        blankline
        print $ ouch1 prepets2
        blankline
        print $ ouch1 prepets3
```

Program 2:

```
module Main where

import Data.List

data Report = Report {recipe :: Recipe,
                      legal  :: Bool,
                      popcnt :: Integer,
                      cost   :: Integer}
              deriving (Eq, Show)

type Recipe = String  -- seven bits to encode seven ingredients

-- recipes in Gray-code order

gray :: Integer -> [Recipe]
gray n
  | n == 0 = [""]
  | n >  0 = map (++"0") (gray (n-1)) ++
             map (++"1") (reverse (gray (n-1)))

recipes = gray 7

-- recipe analysis and report generation

reports = [Report r (legal' r) 6 16 | r <- recipes]  -- fix!

legal_reports = [r | r <- reports, legal r]

legal' :: Recipe -> Bool
legal' r = take 3 r == "000"  -- fix!

ruleset = [rule0, rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5]

-- Rule 0: If truffles, then precisely truffles.
rule0 r = True  -- fix!

-- Rule 1: Either truffles or some meat.
rule1 r = False -- fix!

-- Rule 2: Not both peppers and onions.
rule2 r = True  -- fix!

-- Rule 3: If bacon, then peppers.
rule3 r = False  -- fix!

-- Rule 4: If sausage, then onions.
rule4 r = True  -- fix!

-- Rule 5: If ham, then mushrooms.
rule5 r = False  -- fix!

popcnt' :: Recipe -> Integer
-- number of ingredients
popcnt' x = 3  -- fix!

type Bit  = Char

type Cost = Integer

cost' :: Recipe -> Cost
cost' x = 42  -- fix!

includeCost :: Cost -> Bit -> Cost
includeCost cost bit = if bit == '1' then cost else 0

costs = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]

-- ingredient encoding

peppers   r = r!!0 == '1'

bacon     r = r!!1 == '1'

ham       r = r!!2 == '1'

sausage   r = r!!3 == '1'

onions    r = r!!4 == '1'

mushrooms r = r!!5 == '1'

truffles  r = r!!6 == '1'

preciselyTruffles = (== "0000001")

-- main processing

type Run  = [Report]  -- sequence of legal reports that satisfy the metarule

-- Approach A: Work directly with Grey-code order

runsA = extractRunsA reports

extractRunsA :: [Report] -> [Run]
extractRunsA as
  | clean == [] = []

  | otherwise   = r : extractRunsA as'
                    where (r, as') = break illegal clean
                          clean    = dropWhile illegal as
                          illegal  = not . legal

-- Approach B: Guess a starting seed of a long Hamming run

runsB = extractRunsB legal_reports

extractRunsB :: [Report] -> [Run]
extractRunsB [] = []
extractRunsB xs = run : extractRunsB xs'
                    where run = buildRun (head xs) (tail xs)
                          xs' = xs \\ run  -- list difference

buildRun :: Report -> [Report] -> Run
buildRun seed reports
  | endOfRun  = [seed]

  | otherwise = seed : buildRun seed' reports'
                  where endOfRun   = successors == []
                        successors = filter (.~. seed) reports
                        reports'   = reports \\ [seed]
                        seed'      = head successors

(.~.) :: Report -> Report -> Bool
-- test recipe pairs for Hamming distance 1
x .~. y = True -- fix!

-- print routines

printReports :: [Report] -> IO ()
printReports = putStrLn . unlines . map show

printRecipes :: [Report] -> IO ()
printRecipes = putStrLn . showRecipes

printRuns :: [Run] -> IO ()
printRuns = putStrLn . unlines . map showRecipes

printRuns' :: [Run] -> IO ()
printRuns' = putStrLn . unlines . map showRecipes'

showRecipes :: Run -> String
showRecipes = unlines . map showNames

showRecipes' :: Run -> String
showRecipes' run = (unlines . map showNames) run ++ "  total cost  = $" ++
                   show 15 ++ "\n" ++  -- fix!
                   "  prize money = $" ++ show 4 ++ " million\n"  -- fix!

type Name = String

showNames :: Report -> String
showNames r = (concat . addEggs . translate . recipe) r ++
              "  (" ++ show (popcnt r) ++ ")" ++
              "  $" ++ show (cost r)

translate :: Recipe -> [Name]
translate = zipWith includeName names

includeName :: Name -> Bit -> Name
includeName name bit = if bit == '1' then name else replicate (length name) ' '

addEggs :: [Name] -> [Name]
addEggs = id  -- fix!

names =
  ["peppers ", "bacon ", "ham ", "sausage ", "onions ", "mushrooms ", "truffles"]

blankline = putStrLn ""

render = putStrLn . (++ "\n")

main = do
  blankline
  -- render       "All reports:"
  -- printReports reports
  render       "First ten recipes with number of ingredients and cost:"
  printRecipes $ take 10 reports
  render       "All legal recipes with number of ingredients and cost:"
  printRecipes legal_reports
  render       "All Gray-code runs:"
  printRuns    runsA
  render       "All Gray-code runs with total cost and prize money:"
  printRuns'   runsA
  render       "All seed-generated runs:"
  printRuns    runsB
  render       "All seed-generated runs with total cost and prize money:"
  printRuns'   runsB
```

Comment: Maybe you should learn what does `import` mean?

Answer (score 5):

One lets you use all the functions you can see in [the Data.List module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html) and the other lets you use all the functions defined in [the Data.Char module](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Char.html).

Have a read.

`Data.List` is full of really handy list processing functions. A lot of the functions in Data.List are available anyway because they're in the `Prelude` (which is implicitly imported), but a few aren't

You don't need to `import Data.Char` to work with the type Char, it's for extra functions, mainly for telling what sort of characters you have.

---

You can check what functions they've used from Data.List or Data.Char by editing out the import and reading the error.

Program 1 uses `ord` from Data.Char (see [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ord) to find out what it is or how it works) to calculate the cost of a pet, which seems to depend on the letters in it (and whether a pet is venomous depends on how many letters there are)!

the second one uses `\\` which is list difference (see hoogle to find out what it is or how it works).

Comment: So any program that has character output requires Data.Char? I'm looking at two small programs; one is really small and includes Data.CHar, and the other program is an improvement on the first but only includes the header Data.List. WHat's the explanation?

Comment: @Imray Thanks. I've updated.

Answer (score 4):

they're importing different modules (that is, bringing all functions and datatypes defined in those modules into the current namespace). [Data.List](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base//Data-List.html) contains functions for working with lists such as `++` (append) and `map`; [Data.Char](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base//Data-Char.html) contains functions to do with Chars such as `isAlpha` and `toUpper`.